# javascript not executing on rails edit page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've run into something interesting that I don't quite understand. When using a standard rails scaffold for a model, I navigate to the `#edit` action by clicking the 'Edit' link (/user/1/edit) and JavaScript doesn't execute. As soon as I *refresh* this edit page, JavaScript runs as expected. I'm assuming this is some caching mechanism in rails but I can't figure it out. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

/Edit

In fact, JavaScript doesn't seem to execute on all of the page actions until I do a hard refresh.

Comment: is there turbolinks enabled in your rails app.

Comment: @pkrawat1 ah that seems to be it. thanks! feel free to add an answer for me to accept.

Comment: if you still want turbolinks then go to this link https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: @pkrawat1 answer the question in the answers section and get some reputation brother, you helped out the OP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may arise from turbolinks.
The problem is because the nodes on which you bind events no longer exist.

You can use jquery.turbolinks.js to solve this, if you sill want turbolink's magic.

Just add this gem

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

and in application js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with Turbolinks. http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?view=comments Some additional info about Turbolinks may help you even further.